# How to test click.context.obj mutation in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have a command group with sub-commands. The command group takes the current context through `@click.pass_context` and mutates the ctx.obj (which is carried onto the sub-commands). How can I assert the new value of ctx.obj?

I have tried the following

```
# define a dummy context
ctx = click.Context(command_group_name, obj=dummy_ctx_obj)
with ctx:
  self.runner.invoke(command_group_name, ['sub-command', '--arg', 'value', ], parent=ctx)
  # the bellow assert is failing
  assert isinstance(ctx.obj, expected_type)
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To test `ctx.obj` you need to get the `ctx` object that was used when you ran `self.runner.invoke`.

For reasons unknown to me, Click does not use the `ctx` object you provided with the context manager - it creates its own new one. This is why your assert is failing.

To work around this, you can use the [`mock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) library to capture the actual `click.Context` object used during the test invocation.

```py
from typing import Sequence
from unittest import mock

import click
from click.testing import CliRunner, Result as ClickResult


def invoke_and_get_ctx(
    runner: CliRunner,
    cmd: click.Command,
    args: Sequence[str],
) -> tuple[ClickResult, click.Context]:
    # There doesn't appear to be a good way to get the Click context used by a
    # test invocation, so we replace the invoke method with a wrapper that
    # calls `click.get_current_context` to extract the context object.

    ctx = None

    def extract_ctx(*args, **kwargs):
        nonlocal ctx
        ctx = click.get_current_context()
        return click.Command.invoke(*args, **kwargs)

    with mock.patch("click.Command.invoke", extract_ctx):
        results = runner.invoke(cmd, args)

    return results, ctx
```

Then within your test you would use `invoke_and_get_ctx` like so:

```py
result, ctx = invoke_and_get_ctx(self.runner, command_group_name, ['sub-command', '--arg', 'value'])
assert isinstance(ctx.obj, expected_type)
```

Some adjustments may be needed if you aren't testing a `click.Command` object.

See also [this change](https://github.com/python-jsonschema/check-jsonschema/commit/c39bd818d010ac304cafd2af3432b21083177c07) for how to do this with a Pytest fixture using:

```py
mock.patch(..., side_effect=...)
```